# HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue. What purpose does ExpectContinue serve and under what conditions is it set to true or false.

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpclient

I've been going through some code and have come across

```
  private readonly HttpClient _client;
 _client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

The msdn (https://goo.gl/IoZlB1) doesn't contain much information about ExpectContinue. Also the HttpRequestHeader Enumeration on msdn (https://goo.gl/IoZlB1) describes Expect as

> The Expect header, which specifies particular server behaviors that
>   are required by the client.

I'm hoping if someone can shed some light on ExpectContinue. What is the purpose of it and what happens if it is true or false?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The continue status is used mostly for sending the request headers first, to see if the server will allow (accept) the request. If the server says OK, it sends a 100-continue and the client proceeds with the request body. Otherwise, server responds with 417 (Expectation Failed).

Think that you are going to upload a 1 GB file to a specific folder on a server. If you start the transfer directly and the server does not accept files bigger than 512 MB or the folder does not exist, the server will not accept the file, and the transfer will be a waste of resources for both sides.

Check the W3C documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html)

See section 8.2.3 Use of the 100 (Continue) Status

Comment: Thank you. Is it a good practice to always make a check for continue or only in intensive operations must this be used?

Comment: Expect continue has an overhad of course because it causes at least 1 extra roundtrip. It should be used for resource intensive operations, therefore the default value of ExpectContinue I think is false anyway. I see sometimes that . Net sends this for wcf service requests, but don't know the motive behind it.

Comment: HTTP does not know any folders, you are providing false assumptions here.