# How to use HttpClient.PostAsync asynchronous when the URL responds after an artificial timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

**How can [HttpClient.PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx) be used to post HTTP requests to URLs which have an artificial time for sending back a response.**

Please note the URL and the parameter **sleep=30** which is used to introduce an artificial delay of 30 seconds before sending back an HTTP response.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Start time : " + DateTime.Now);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        { 
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://fake-response.appspot.com/api/?data={Hello World}&sleep=30");
                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://fake-response.appspot.com/api/?data={Hello World}&status=200");

                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters["ContentType"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";

                //Create Task to POST to the URL
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
                var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));

                Task<bool> b1 = ProcessURLAsync(response, 1, 5, 2);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End time : " + DateTime.Now);
```

What needs to be done is that async HTTP Posts need to be made in a loop and should not be dependent on the timeout specified in the URL.
However, the PostAsync times out before a response is received.

Please check the time needed for POSTing the 2 different URLs in a loop of 10 async POSTs

I checked [HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494609/httpclient-defaultrequestheaders-expectcontinue-what-purpose-does-expectcontinu) , but I do not think this might help in this use case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I guess you want an infinite timeout?

Comment: @KooKiz - that is an alternative, but that would not make the requests async

Comment: So you expect request to take 30 seconds, but set timeout to 10 seconds, and it times out. What's wrong here?

Comment: @Evk The timeout of 10 seconds is for the network timeout, whereas the artificial delay at the server end is not known ahead of time. Basically the client should POST the requests and move ahead and process the response async, when available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That artificial delay is no different from network timeout, from client's perspective. So you should set `client.Timeout` to the maximum expected artificial delay + real network timeout time. If you don't want to block waiting for response - just not `await` Task returned from PostAsync. You can store all such tasks in some list and wait them all to complete with `await Task.WhenAll(yourTaskList)`. Or you can use `ContinueWith` to perform specific actions when given task will be completed. However, if you care about response at all - you have to set large enough timeout anyway, otherwise request will be aborted prematurely.

Here is some sample code to help you out

```
    static async void MakeRequests()
    {
        var requests = new List<Task<bool>>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            // no await here, so, not await MakeRequest(i);
            requests.Add(MakeRequest(i));
        }
        // now all 10 requests are running in parallel
        try {
            await Task.WhenAll(requests);
        }
        catch {
           // no need to handle it here - we handle all errors below 
        }

        // if we are here, all requests are either completed or failed, inspect their results
        foreach (var request in requests) {
            if (request.IsCanceled) {
                // failed by timeout
            }
            else if (request.IsFaulted) {
                // failed
                Log(request.Exception);
            }
            else {
                // success
                bool result = request.Result;
                // handle your result here if needed
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task<bool> MakeRequest(int i) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://fake-response.appspot.com/api/?data={Hello World}&sleep=30");
            //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://fake-response.appspot.com/api/?data={Hello World}&status=200");
            // no timeout here, or set to max expected delay
            //client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["ContentType"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";

            //Create Task to POST to the URL
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
            var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));

            Task<bool> b1 = ProcessURLAsync(response, 1, 5, 2);
            return b1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The responses do need to be processed.
So basically, either we wait for a single response ( or the sum time of all the responses ), both of which do not solve the issue ( of POSTing async requests - with an artificial response time ). Though this does not solve the issue, but I think this would be close to the answer, however would await further inputs.

Comment: Well I don't really understand what you need. You make several requests in parallel (by **not** awaiting the Task), then you wait not for _sum_ of times of all responses, but you wait for _max_ of times of their responses (because they are performed in parallel). If you want to process each response immediatly when it's awailable - use ContinueWith (without await).

Comment: I have edited the source code in the question.
   The best way to understand this use case is to check the time taken for making 10 POSTs to the 2 different URLs in the sample code above. There is a huge time difference in the time needed to POST when the URL contains an artificial time delay, although async is used.

Comment: @SanjayKaria I have added sample code to help you understand the problem.

Comment: Collecting all the tasks, without awaiting them and then waiting for all of them worked out.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the PostAsync times out before a response is received.

This method times out because you set `HttpClient.Timeout` property to 10 seconds. Setting this property instructs the client to time out after a specified time if response is not received.

Comment: If we do not set the timeout, it will default to 100 seconds and will timeout for artificial delays > 100sec

The main point is that, irrespective of the timeout, the processing halts on the line - 

var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)); 

waiting for the response from the request, instead of moving further.
 
This waiting does not happen when we remove the artificial delay (sleep=30) from the URL

Comment: Another user has answered your question already: You have to 1) increase the timeout that you set on HttpClient; 2) do not call await on after PostAsync, but collect all the tasks that are returned from calling PostAsync into a list, and then call await Task.WhenAll(tasks)